# is Mail_files is a function?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

```
DEFINE VARIABLE wlc-Identifiant AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE wlc-file-txt    AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

wlc-Identifiant = STRING(YEAR(TODAY), "9999") + STRING(MONTH(TODAY), "99") + STRING(DAY(TODAY), "99") + REPLACE(STRING(TIME, "HH:MM:SS"), ":", "").
wlc-file-txt = wlc-Identifiant + "foo.txt".

DEFINE STREAM outStr.
OUTPUT STREAM outStr TO VALUE (wlc-file-txt).

FOR EACH customer NO-LOCK:
  EXPORT STREAM outStr customer.
END.
OUTPUT STREAM outStr CLOSE.

RUN sendmail.p (INPUT wlc-file-txt). /* add the file in parameter */

/*OS-DELETE foo.txt.*/ /* It 's a cron job */

Sendmail.p
DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER wlpic-file-txt AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE STREAM stMail.
OUTPUT STREAM stMail THROUGH
   "mail_files -f foo@bar.com -t me@here.com -s\"subject\" -b~\" + wlpic-file-txt + "\").
PUT STREAM stMail "Email body".
OUTPUT STREAM stMail CLOSE.
```

Comment: The best would be to ask zarose who wrote it in his question :[Multiple OS-COMMAND are conflicting calls from procedure] (http://stackoverflow.com/q/24042718/3351765) :)

Comment: If I had to render a guess: -f = from address, -t = to address, -s = subject line of the email, -b = body of the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case mail_files appears to be an external UNIX command.  Probably a script.

You might get very similar functionality using mailx which is available on pretty much every UNIX system.

If -f is supposed to be "From" in the mail_files script then -f probably becomes -r

Likewise if -t is supposed to be "to" it just gets eliminated, mailx assumes an unadorned argument is the "to" address.  Mailx will use any text on standard input as the body.  So instead of -b you would just write to the stream (the 'PUT STREAM stMail "Email body".' command that you see.)  You can attach a file with mailx  using -a.

Comment: tom,COULD YOU TELL ME WHAT -f,-t,-b,-s refers to?

Comment: You need to find and read the script.  It is not a standard part of UNIX.  doydoy44 seems to have found a link to something that looks like what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

No, I think it's a command line of Thunderbird.
I found [this](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=327770) this morning.